# append the URL so that it will not give 404

Tags: php, javascript, html, url

I want to append something in the URLs so that it remains the valid one.

For Ex:

The Orignal URL is : http://www.menards.com/main/appliances/air-conditioners-dehumidifiers/soleus-12-000-btu-portable-air-conditioner-with-heat-pump/p-1754474-c-5571.htm

The appended one : http://www.menards.com/main/appliances/air-conditioners-dehumidifiers/soleus-12-000-btu-portable-air-conditioner-with-heat-pump/p-1754474-c-5571.htm&sort=

I want to add something anywhere in this URL so that it will not give 404 Page Not Found.

"I want to do it for some specific reason"

Comment: Very bad design if you want to implement it that way. Just make a default sort if no sort variable is provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To append vars to the end of a url, the first one needs to start with the question mark (`?`), with subsequent variables added with an ampersand (`&`).

For example:

```
'http://my.site.com/index.html?variable1=hello&variable2=goodbye'
```

This can be done for *"any number of specific reasons"*